# Parentless Dialog Box

Tags: android, android-dialog

I'm trying to develop an application that transmit data over wifi. I want to create a **dialog box** that prompts users whether to accept data or not (just like the popup you get while receiving data via bluetooth). How is it possible ? 
If it is possible only with the help of Floating Window, can anyone provide a good tutorial link?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an activity that uses a theme like `Theme.Dialog`, so that it looks like a dialog, even though it is an activity. You cannot have a `Dialog` that is not associated with an activity.

Comment: `Theme.Dialog` along with `AlertDialog` solved my problem. Thanks a lot for your help! :)